# Why is my tensorflow-gpu running in Intel-HD GPU instead of NVIDIA?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I've installed tensorflow-gpu in my machine. While checking whether it shows GPU or not in device list from:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
  print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

[image]

It clearly shows there is NVIDIA 1050 Ti GPU in list. But when training dataset and checking on Task Manager, I got this

[image]

How's this even possible? Why is tensorflow using INTEL-HD instead of NVIDIA? Also it shows OOM error while training.

Comment: You are misintepreting the data, nothing shows that tensorflow is running in the Intel GPU, because it does not support it at all.

Comment: Go to the back of your computer and plug your monitor cable into the GPU instead of the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set NVIDIA GPU either as default GPU for every operation (in Nvidia Control Panel thing) or set that Python should be ran with NVIDIA GPU (also in Nvidia manager). Otherwise computer will automatically start the built-in Intel GPU by default.